# Run a script after killing lxsession (xorg)

Tags: linux, bash, xorg, tty, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a program automatically within a bash script after killing the LXDE session. My script consists of:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill lxsession;
sh /home/pi/RetroPie/EmulationStation/emulationstation
```

I tried this as well:

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup & pkill lxsession & 
writevt /dev/tty1 'emulationstation'
```

My aim is to log out of the LXDE session and run EmulationStation on my Raspberry Pi with a bash script. I'm using `pkill lxsession;` to bypass lxsession's logout confirmation dialog.

As it stands, this script just gets me to the command line from a working LXDE desktop. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you get this to work ever? I'm having the EXACT same issue as you with EmulationStation and Raspbian desktop icons :(

Comment: I never did. You might be able to use systemd though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. You run this script from a terminal emulator that is itself running within the LXDE session. When you kill the LXDE session, you also kill the terminal and, therefore, your script.

A possible workaround would be to log in via a different tty and run your script there. What exactly are you trying to do? Would a root cronjob work?

Comment: I'm trying to create a shortcut on my desktop that logs out of LXDE/Xorg and then runs the emulator front end EmulationStation which cannot be run while X is running. I was fairly sure it was possible to send a command to a newly opened terminal but I could be mistaken. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The `writevt` isn't available here, but I assume it just emulates tty input.

You could try starting a command in the tty *before* killing the X session, and have it wait until the X sessoin is killed. How about

```
#!/bin/sh
writevt /dev/tty1 'sleep 20s; emulationstation'` & 
pkill lxsession
```

Comment: I had to remove the back-tick before the `&` to get your code to run. It just dropped me to tty1 just like my code above. Thank you for your suggestion though. There has to be a way to this with bash.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'screen' when you either run the script from the terminal, or when you create a launcher:

```
screen ./emu-script.sh
```

screen will keep your terminal session alive even if LXDE kills, or whatever else you have shutdown. That way your script can finish properly